# Symfony Finder exclude with glob

Tags: php, symfony, php-cs-fixer, symfony-finder

I am trying to run PHP CS Fixer, which I believe is based on Symfony (which I am not familiar with), and having a problem with excluding some paths.

My setup is below:

```
$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->exclude('lib/adodb')
    ->exclude('lib/bbcode')
    ->exclude('lib/joomla')
    ->exclude('lib/JSON')
    ->exclude('lib/pear')
    ->exclude('lib/phpass')
    ->exclude('lib/smarty')
    ->exclude('lib/smtp')
    ->exclude('modules/*/lib')  
    ->name('*.class')
    ->name('*.inc')
    ->name('*.php')
;
```

Basically, I will like to exclude:

```
modules/ANYNAME/lib/ANYFILE
modules/ANYNAME/lib/ANYSUBDIR/ANYFILE
```

But I find that the `->exclude('modules/*/lib')` line is not catching these. For instance, `modules/somemodule/lib/somefile.inc` is still processed.

I had thought that this was because I had `->name('*.inc')` but it seems to happen with or without that line.

The other excludes work fine except the `->exclude('modules/*/lib')` one.

Any pointers?

## ** Correction/Update **

It does seem that the issue is with the name selector. Seems it is not allowed to select `*.inc` using `name` for instance and then try to exclude those found in `modules/xyz/lib`.

Overcoming this would solve my issue

Comment: There is `notPath()` method http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.html#method_notPath Would it work ?

Comment: Thanks. Doing some tests, it does seem that the issue is with the `name` selector. Seems it is not allowed to select `*.inc` using `name` for instance and then try to exclude those found in `modules/xyz/lib`

Comment: @Dayo I'm little lost so is my understanding right? You want to exclude everything under `modules`?

Comment: @BentCoder. I have several folders under modules and some of them have a lib folder. I want to exclude anything under such lib folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP CS Fixer could accept any iterable as finder.
Indeed, default one is just a symfony/finder (https://github.com/symfony/finder/blob/master/Finder.php).

As you can see, `exclude` is not accepting a glob.
You could use, eg, `notPath`:

```
$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->notPath('#modules/.*/lib#')
    ->name('*.inc');
```

Let say you have following structure:
    $ ls -lR
    .:
    total 8
    drwxr-xr-x 2 keradus keradus 4096 Mai  5 20:32 a
    drwxr-xr-x 3 keradus keradus 4096 Mai  5 20:31 modules

```
./a:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 keradus keradus 24 Mai  5 20:35 a.inc

./modules:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 keradus keradus 4096 Mai  5 20:31 ANYNAME

./modules/ANYNAME:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 keradus keradus 4096 Mai  5 20:31 lib

./modules/ANYNAME/lib:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 keradus keradus   24 Mai  5 20:35 b.inc
drwxr-xr-x 2 keradus keradus 4096 Mai  5 20:32 sub

./modules/ANYNAME/lib/sub:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 keradus keradus 24 Mai  5 20:35 c.inc
```

Even when all of that 3 files violates coding standards, only one (not excluded by finder) would be fixed:

```
$ php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run -vvv
Loaded config default from "/home/keradus/tmp/.php_cs.dist".
F
Legend: ?-unknown, I-invalid file syntax, file ignored, S-Skipped, .-no changes, F-fixed, E-error
   1) a/a.inc (braces)
```

Comment: Accepting as tests against this minimal setup works as explained. Need to figure out why I still have issues with my actual setup.

Comment: If you need to exclude ONLY the directory in the root, then between the characters `#` you need to use a **regular expression**, for example: `notPath('#^lib#')`. Or if you need to exclude only the most nested directories, then: `notPath('#lib$#')`